# char array to int array

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a string to an array of integers so I could then perform math operations on them. I'm having trouble with the following bit of code:

```
String raw = "1233983543587325318";

char[] list = new char[raw.length()];
list = raw.toCharArray();
int[] num = new int[raw.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++){
    num[i] = (int[])list[i];
}

System.out.println(num);
```

This is giving me an "inconvertible types" error, required: int[] found: char
I have also tried some other ways like Character.getNumericValue and just assigning it directly, without any modification. In those situations, it always outputs the same garbage "[I@41ed8741", no matter what method of conversion I use or (!) what the value of the string actually is. Does it have something to do with unicode conversion?

Comment: Side note: the `char[] list = new char[raw.length()];` allocates a new array and assigns it to the list variable, but the next line assigns another array to the same variable. The first line is thus unnecessary, and allocates memory for nothing. You should just use `char[] list = raw.toCharArray();`

Comment: `System.out.println(num);` will not print anything of much interest :)

Comment: Just a quick question: after executing this, should `num[i]` be `1` or be `49`? Because just casting `char` to `int` the way you are trying to do it, will result in `49` which is a ascii-code of `1`.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you, corrected

dasblinkenlight, actually, it doesn't, but it prints out "[@41ed8741" no matter what string of numbers i use

npe, you are right, I tested with num[5] (the number 8) and that printed 56 (the ascii for 8). so how would i go about converting it from ascii?

Comment: @daedalus That string the `println(num)` prints simply tells you that you printed an array at a certain address, regardless of the array's content. Use `println(Arrays.toString(num))` instead.

Comment: @daedalus take a look at `Integer.parseInt(String s);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your solution. The first is the loop condition `i > raw.length()` is wrong - your loops is never executed - thecondition should be `i < raw.length()`

The second is the cast. You're attempting to cast to an integer array. In fact since the result is a char you don't have to cast to an int - a conversion will be done automatically. But the converted number isn't what you think it is. It's not the integer value you expect it to be but is in fact the ASCII value of the char. So you need to subtract the ASCII value of zero to get the integer value you're expecting.

The third is how you're trying to print the resultant integer array. You need to loop through each element of the array and print it out.

```
    String raw = "1233983543587325318";

    int[] num = new int[raw.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++){
        num[i] = raw.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    for (int i : num) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Comment: Finaly, someone noticed, that `(int)list[i]` gives ascii-code! +1 for that. But add, or remove the curly braces - you're not being consistent.

Comment: Thanks, this fixes everything  :). Thanks for explaining the ASCII part, I guess I need to read up on that now.

Comment: `System.out.println(i);` could be inside the first for as `System.out.println(num[i]);`

Answer (score 15):

Two ways in Java 8:

```
String raw = "1233983543587325318";

final int[] ints1 = raw.chars()
    .map(x -> x - '0')
    .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints1));

final int[] ints2 = Stream.of(raw.split(""))
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints2));
```

The second solution is probably quite inefficient as it uses a regular expression and creates string instances for every digit.

Comment: Excellent examples of very concise code in Java 8! Interesting that you can specify an empty string for the regular expression for the call to `raw.split("")`.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone have correctly identified the invalid cast in your code. You do not need that cast at all: Java will convert `char` to `int` implicitly:

```
String raw = "1233983543587325318";

char[] list = raw.toCharArray();
int[] num = new int[raw.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++) {
    num[i] = Character.digit(list[i], 10);
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works the same without any conversion. I tried that earlier, and it gave me the same jumble when I try to do System.out.println(num);. I used num[5] instead (should be "8"), and it printed 56, which is the ASCII value for 8. So.. how would I convert from ASCII? Sorry, very beginner here, just learning the language through doing.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be casting each element to an integer array `int[]` but to an integer `int`:

```
for (int i = 0; i > raw.length(); i++)
{
   num[i] = (int)list[i];
}

System.out.println(num);
```

Answer (score 2):

this line:

```
num[i] = (int[])list[i];
```

should be:

```
num[i] = (int)list[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast `list[i]` to `int[]`, but to `int`. Each index of the array is just an int, not an array of ints.

So it should be just

```
num[i] = (int)list[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

For future references. char to int conversion is not implicitly, even with cast. You have to do something like that:

```
    String raw = "1233983543587325318";

    char[] list = raw.toCharArray();
    int[] num = new int[list.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        num[i] = list[i] - '0';
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
```

Comment: Reducing the '0' from the char array is what is required to convert the values of the character array to int element. Rest all the comments mentioned above doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anyone else mentioning the obvious:

We can skip the char array and go directly from String to int array.
Since java 8 we have [CharSequence.chars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) which will return an [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) so to get an int array, of the char to int values, from a string.

```java
String raw = "1233983543587325318";
int[] num = raw.chars().toArray();
// num ==> int[19] { 49, 50, 51, 51, 57, 56, 51, 53, 52, 51, 53, 56, 55, 51, 50, 53, 51, 49, 56 }
```

There are also some math reduce functions on `Intstream` like `sum`, `average`, etc. if this is your end goal then we can skip the int array too.

```java
String raw = "1233983543587325318";
int sum = raw.chars().sum();
// sum ==> 995
```

nJoy!

Answer (score 0):

This class here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html should hep you out. It can parse the integers from a string. It would be a bit easier than using arrays.

Comment: You should link current documentation.

Comment: Okay, should be up to date on that, I had an older copy bookmarked for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is right about the conversion problem. It looks like you actually tried a correct version but the output was garbeled. This is because `system.out.println(num)` doesn't do what you want it to in this case:) Use `system.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(num))` instead, and see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
String raw = "1233983543587325318";
char[] c = raw.toCharArray();
int[] a = new int[raw.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++) {
   a[i] = (int)c[i] - 48;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
String raw = "1233983543587325318";

char[] list = new char[raw.length()];
list = raw.toCharArray();
int[] num = new int[raw.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < raw.length(); i++) {
    num[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(list[i]));
}

for (int i: num) {
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and modern solution

```
int[] result = new int[raw.length()]; 
Arrays.setAll(result, i -> Character.getNumericValue(raw.charAt(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Line `num[i] = (int[])list[i];`

It should be `num[i] = (int) list[i];`
You are looping through the array so you are casting each individual item in the array.

The reason you got "garbage" is you were printing the int values in the num[] array.
char values are not a direct match for int values.
char values in java use UTF-16 Unicode.
For example the "3" char translates to 51 int

To print out the final int[] back to char use this loop

```
for(int i:num)
        System.out.print((char) i);
```